# add up multiple attributes of same index?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have **3 curves and a target curve**

How do I **add up the attribute**(offset for example) of every point, and **transfer to the target curve** based on index?

[image]

Comment: Attribute Statistic node can only excute and output to one point at a time. Do I need something like repeat zone?

Comment: Accumulated field node with a sample index will do!
[Answered by zeroskilz at blenderartists.org](https://blenderartists.org/t/add-up-multiple-attributes-of-same-index/1484260/3?u=azona77)

Answer (score -1):

Accumulated field node with a sample index will do!
[Answered by zeroskilz at blenderartists.org](https://blenderartists.org/t/add-up-multiple-attributes-of-same-index/1484260/3?u=azona77)

Comment: Thanks for the posts. This is not a regular forum, according to site rules [links to answers are not answers](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2382) if the link goes missing your answer becomes an empty shell without content. Answers should be substantial and stand on their own without relying on external data like links, videos or images. Instead of having users go through external links, either transcribe essential parts of the process here, linking the source, or posts these in the comments section instead.